# Cannot resolve Symbol LENGTH_LONG

Tags: android

i am beginner i am facing with that problem that cannot resolve symbol length_long ,i used Android studio 2.2.3 and i change my all versions in grid, but still the same problem

```
private void showLocationSettings() {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainCoordinatorLayout, "Location Error: GPS Disabled!",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Enable", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
    snackbar.setDuration(Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

Comment: have you try File-->invalidate-caches-restart

Comment: sir i tried but fail

Comment: hey your image is not visible..please explain your question in detail..

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpzq7N_sjSAhUDQBoKHTiqBkEQFgg0MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F42040916%2Ferror-with-method-make-and-symbol-length-long-in-snackbar&usg=AFQjCNF95tnMFnOf2vHP1hp-ClA-6VPOxg&sig2=r0v5i6l5ARWp3gVRsrYBJw

Comment: sir please check this i am facing with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your compileSdkVersion,buildToolsVersion,minSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion  and dependencies.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.test.app"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
 }
  buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
  }
   dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
   }
```

Comment: OK sir just wait i will give response